# Error installing spacy using pip3

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

> While installing spacy on a virtual environment on Mac I am getting
>   this problem, cannot find a way to sort this is out.

**I'm using python 3.7 version**

> Failed building wheel for cytoolz
>
> Failed building wheel for preshed

the error I am getting is

**error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1**

I am trying to install spacy in a virtual environment on MAC. is there is way I can build the wheels manually and then proceed with the installation

```
Collecting cytoolz<0.9,>=0.8 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/e6/ccc124714dcc1bd511e64ddafb4d5d20ada2533b92e3173a4cf09e0d0831/cytoolz-0.8.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in ./.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cytoolz<0.9,>=0.8->thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy) (0.9.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: preshed, cytoolz
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for preshed ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/ajiteshsingh/.virtualenvs/testenv/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-install-rmzmlyii/preshed/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-wheel-0fw7edno --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed
  copying preshed/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed
  copying preshed/about.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed/tests
  copying preshed/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed/tests
  copying preshed/tests/test_pop.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed/tests
  copying preshed/tests/test_counter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed/tests
  copying preshed/tests/test_hashing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed/tests
  copying preshed/counter.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed
  copying preshed/maps.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed
  copying preshed/maps.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed
  copying preshed/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed
  copying preshed/counter.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed
  running build_ext
  building 'preshed.maps' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-install-rmzmlyii/preshed/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c preshed/maps.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed/maps.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
  preshed/maps.cpp:1128:35: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'long' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
        __pyx_t_1 = ((__pyx_v_power < __pyx_v_initial_size) != 0);
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:1564:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 48; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:1556:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 48; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:1835:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 52; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:1827:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 52; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:2610:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 78; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:2602:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 78; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:3614:34: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'const __pyx_t_7preshed_4maps_key_t' (aka 'const unsigned long long') [-Wsign-compare]
      __pyx_t_1 = (((__pyx_v_i[0]) < __pyx_v_map_->length) != 0);
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:3701:32: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'const __pyx_t_7preshed_4maps_key_t' (aka 'const unsigned long long') [-Wsign-compare]
    __pyx_t_1 = (((__pyx_v_i[0]) == __pyx_v_map_->length) != 0);
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:3778:32: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long long' [-Wsign-compare]
    __pyx_t_1 = (((__pyx_v_i[0]) == (__pyx_v_map_->length + 1)) != 0);
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  preshed/maps.cpp:6642:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  preshed/maps.cpp:6643:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  preshed/maps.cpp:6644:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  preshed/maps.cpp:6645:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
      tstate->exc_type = *type;
      ~~~~~~  ^
  preshed/maps.cpp:6646:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tstate->exc_value = *value;
              ^~~~~~~~~
              curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  preshed/maps.cpp:6647:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tstate->exc_traceback = *tb;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
              curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  10 warnings and 6 errors generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for preshed
  Running setup.py clean for preshed
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cytoolz ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/ajiteshsingh/.virtualenvs/testenv/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-install-rmzmlyii/cytoolz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-wheel-chjimkew --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/compatibility.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/utils_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/_signatures.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/curried
  copying cytoolz/curried/operator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/curried
  copying cytoolz/curried/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/curried
  copying cytoolz/curried/exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/curried
  copying cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/functoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/recipes.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/utils.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/utils.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/recipes.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/functoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/dicttoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/cpython.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/itertoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_none_safe.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_curried.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_compatibility.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_embedded_sigs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_functoolz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_inspect_args.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_doctests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_tlz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_signatures.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/dev_skip_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_recipes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_docstrings.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_dev_skip_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_dicttoolz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_serialization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_itertoolz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/tests
  running build_ext
  building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c cytoolz/dicttoolz.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cytoolz/dicttoolz.o
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:8277:65: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 3, have 4
      return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                     ^~~~
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/include/stddef.h:105:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
  #  define NULL ((void*)0)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9053:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      *type = tstate->exc_type;
              ~~~~~~  ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9054:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      *value = tstate->exc_value;
                       ^~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9055:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9062:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9063:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9064:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9065:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tstate->exc_type = type;
      ~~~~~~  ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9066:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tstate->exc_value = value;
              ^~~~~~~~~
              curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9067:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
              curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9122:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9123:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9124:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9125:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tstate->exc_type = local_type;
      ~~~~~~  ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9126:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tstate->exc_value = local_value;
              ^~~~~~~~~
              curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:9127:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
              curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  16 errors generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cytoolz
  Running setup.py clean for cytoolz
Failed to build preshed cytoolz
Installing collected packages: preshed, cytoolz, thinc, spacy
  Running setup.py install for preshed ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/ajiteshsingh/.virtualenvs/testenv/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-install-rmzmlyii/preshed/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-record-o06l53ma/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ajiteshsingh/.virtualenvs/testenv/bin/../include/site/python3.7/preshed:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'preshed.maps' extension
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-install-rmzmlyii/preshed/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c preshed/maps.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/preshed/maps.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
    clang: error: no such file or directory: 'preshed/maps.cpp'
    clang: error: no input files
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/ajiteshsingh/.virtualenvs/testenv/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-install-rmzmlyii/preshed/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-record-o06l53ma/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ajiteshsingh/.virtualenvs/testenv/bin/../include/site/python3.7/preshed" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9c/mqzz21tn725dx98p9jkqlm740000gn/T/pip-install-rmzmlyii/preshed/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (24 July 2018): Spacy has been updated for python 3.7.**

Spacy hasn't been updated for Python 3.7 yet.

From Matthew Honnibal (author of Spacy) a few days ago:
"Python 3.7 just came out, and while I don't think there's any deep incompatibilities, I think we do need to add specifiers for the new version to our various dependencies. Could you try installing with Python 3.6?"

Source: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2524:

Comment: That's odd!  Before I updated my comment I tested Spacy 2.0.12 in a python 3.7.0 venv on my Macbook (High Sierra 10.13.6).  It's installed and working fine.  I've got LLVM version 9.1.0 with clang-902.0.39.2.  Any differences in your setup?

Comment: @Chris I am trying on Mac Mojave 10.14.2 and I am getting the same error. How could be done?

Comment: @MithileshKumar I've created [a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/185595/spacy-install-errors) to discuss, happy to try to help there.